# requirejs loads incorrect filename and filepath

Tags: javascript, requirejs, file-not-found

I have a huge problem. Why is requirejs set his own filenames??

here my example. in the header, I set up requirejs like this

```
<script data-main="src/dist/scripts/config.min" src=src/dist/scripts/vendor/require.min.js"></script>
```

And the unminified config file looks like this

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    bootstrap: 'vendor/bootstrap.min',
    jquery: 'vendor/jquery.min',
    focuspoint: 'vendor/jquery.focuspoint.min',
    microplugin: 'vendor/microplugin.min',
    selectite: 'vendor/selectize.min',
    sifter: 'vendor/sifter.min',
    swiper: 'vendor/swiper.min',
    tether: 'vendor/tether.min'
  }
});
```

this is like it looks in my file structure

[image]:

Now the problem I get. Requirejs want to load different filenames from different folder and not from for example src/scripts/dist/**vendor/** folder. Here a screenshot:

[image]

This is an example of a js file, where i load for example jquery:

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {
  //some code ...
});
```

What is wrong? I don't get it...

Comment: You didnt put the .js extension to those files. [reference to read](https://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles)

Comment: it's not looking for the .min versions at all, see if you've config requirejs twice. like, your trying to load `jquery.focuspoint.min`but require is looking for `focuspoint.js`

Comment: @HamletLeon You don't need the. .js extension. you can see, it want's to load jquery.js and i defined vendor/jquery.min. but it does no load the right file name, neither from correct path...

Comment: @Anuga No, i only have one config file...